# Generating primes with gap $B \le 246$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Due to the work of Yitang Zhang, James Maynard, Terence Tao and the Polymath8 project we know the current bound on prime gaps is 246. i.e, there are infinitely many pairs of primes that differ by a gap no more than $B, B \le 246$.

I was wondering if there is a systematic way to generate a subset of these primes. (We don't have to generate all, but the ones we generate should be pairs of primes with gap $\le 246$).

We could do sieving for primes in a range and then check for a prime $p$ in the range whether $p+246$ is also prime. Is there any other way?

EDIT: My understanding of the gap theorem was clarified in the comments section and I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Do you want the gap between two consecutive primes to be $246$; or are you just looking for any two primes (consecutive or not) that differ by $246$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  The method you suggest should easily produce many billions of prime pairs with gap 246--or any other small even number.  (There's nothing intrinsically special about 246; it's only special in terms of what we can prove with current methods.)  Do you want large examples, examples of a special form, etc.?  Or are you asking whether the Polymath result is constructive in some sense?

Comment: Some background info: I chose 246 since it is proven that infinitely many pairs exist with that gap as I did not want to rely on the Twin Prime conjecture being true. I am trying to represent an integer $z$ as the sum of a prime and an integer in the range [0,246], if the integer falls within a pair of primes that meet this criteria. If not, I am trying to get the closest prime to $z$ of this kiind.

Comment: @paw88789: Since I am relying on the prime gap theorem, I guess the same conditions apply. So, just primes with gap $B = 246$.

Comment: It is NOT known whether there are infinite many prime gaps with value exactly $246$. It is only known that there are infinite many prime gaps not exceeding $246$.

Comment: The only way we can find large primes with a "small" gap to the next prime is currently brute force. For several hundred digits, we can find such examples still relatively easy, but with increasing magnitude it becomes more and more difficult. Which magnitude should the pairs you are looking for have ?

Comment: @Peter: $O(1024 bits)$

Comment: Then, with a little patience, PARI/GP should be enough to collect enough examples of any even gap magnitude from $2$ to $246$. There are surely faster number theory tools , but pari/gp is easiest to handle. The numbers are also small enough to be proven to be prime.

Comment: @Peter: Your other comment was surprising. I checked Terry Tao's slides on this: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/lat.pdf and he says: "In [X, 2X] for large X, one can make $p_{n+1} − p_n$ less than$ ... " and he goes on to list the bounds...
"4,680 *(Polymath8a, 27 July 2013)*, 
600 *(Maynard, 19 Nov 2013)*, 
246 *(Polymath8b, 14 Apr 2014)*". Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115308/discussion-between-peter-and-vvgiri).